# Cipher syntax? Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in server.ovpn:12: data-ciphers (2.6_beta1)

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to get the right cypher syntax.

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\server.crt"
cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\issued\\server.crt"
key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\private\\server.key"
dh "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\dh2048.pem"
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth ca.key 0 # This file is secret
data-ciphers cipher AES-256-CBC
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
explicit-exit-notify 1
```

Error

```
Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in server.ovpn:12: data-ciphers (2.6_beta1)
```

Comment: Why are you running a version of OpenVPN from 2018? You really shouldn’t use the version you are attempting to run.

Answer (score -1):

> trying to get the right cypher syntax.

You have a major syntax error.

**data-ciphers cipher** should be **data-ciphers_cipher**

Based on documentation AES-256-CBC should already be the default fallback cipher for the version of OpenVPN you are running.

Source: [Change encryption cipher in Access Server](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/change-encryption-cipher-in-access-server/#:%7E:text=The%20data-channel%20encryption%20cipher%20encrypts%20and%20decrypts%20the,on%20a%20cipher%20that%20both%20support%20and%20allow)